# Alternative to ls | grep

Tags: command-line, files, find, directory, search

I'm trying to search through the files and directories of a specific folder. For example, I was looking in `/usr/bin` for my `python` binaries. To do so, I used `ls | grep python`. When I did this, I was able to find, for example, `python3`, `python3-config`, etc.

While this works fine, I know that there are  easier ways to do that: I shouldn't have to pipe to `grep`. But when I tried `find . -name python`, as per my understanding of the `find` man page, it yielded no results.

I know that `grep` searches through a file. What is the correct way to search through a given directory?

Comment: Your question is confusing. What exactly are you trying to find?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Does that edit explain it better?

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer. You can wait a bit before accepting if some other person provide a better one... (you could just upvote it for now, if it helps you!)

Comment: @OlivierDulac Your answer is basically exactly what I was looking for--I think you earned the check mark, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do several things, using "globbing"
In a nutshell: the shell tries to match

```
? to any character, (unless it is "protected" by single or double quotes
* to any string of characters (even empty ones), unless protected by single or double quotes 
[abc] can match either 'a', 'b' or 'c'
[^def] is any single character different than 'd', 'e' or 'f'
```

So to match under /usr/bin anything with python in it:

```
ls -d /usr/bin/*python*  # just looks into that directory
```

or with find, you can also use globbing. However you need to surround it in quotes so that the shell does not expand them, but instead give them to the find command with the '*' intact:

```
find /usr/bin -name '*python*'  # could descend into subfolders if present
```

Comment: Nice answer. But you seem to have used "as is" in a strange way. No I think it is the "and" I had to re-parse 3 times, and then I got what you mean. The natural reading is "expand them and ...". I think I have a fix.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor : I reworded the "as is" ^^ thx for pointing it out. I am French, and sometimes I won't use the proper way to express things in English.

Comment: I think the "as is" was fine. The problem was with the natural parsing order (left to right) cased a [crash blosom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldT2g2qDQNQ) (make the and attach to the wrong thing)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  : thx for the link! (and for your edit!)